# Fringe-detection algorithm for hierarchical structure

Tags: algorithm, tree, hierarchy

My back-end (Java) is heavily relying on Tree structures with strong inheritance. Conflict resolution is complex so I am looking to test way to simply block users when the propagation of changes in higher nodes has not yet reached the current element.

Hierarchies are represented through both Materialized Paths and Adjacency Lists for performance reasons. The goal would be to;

- Prevent update (bad request) when API requests the change of a node with pending propagation
- Inform user through the DTO (e.g. `isLocked` attribute) when they retrieve a node with pending propagation

Propagation is a simple matter of going through all nodes in a top-down fashion, previously level-by-level (which would have been easier) but now is no longer orchestrated: each node sends the message to its children.

At the moment I have two ideas I do not like:

1. Add a `locked` flag on each node (persisted in DB), toggle it to `true` for all descendants of a modified node, then each node can be unlocked after being processed.
2. Leverage the materialized path and record the current unprocessed node in a new table. If node `D` with path `A.B.C.D` is queried, any of the 4 path nodes in DB means the node has not been processed yet and should be locked.

I do not like approach 1 because it needs to update all entities twice, although retrieving the list would be quick with the Materialized Path.

I do not like approach 2 because:

- The materialized path is stored as `VARCHAR2`, thus the comparison cannot be done in DB and I would first have to unwrap the path to get all nodes in the path and then query the DB to check for any of the elements in hierarchy.
- Trees can be quite large with hundreds of children per node, tens of thousands of nodes per tree. Modifying the root would create a huge amount of those temporary records holding the current 'fringe' of the propagation. That many independent DB calls is not ideal, especially since nodes can often be processed in less than 10 ms. I'd probably quickly encounter a bottleneck and bad performances.

Is there another approach that could be taken to identify whether a propagation has reached a node? Examples, comparisons, ... Anything that could help decide on the best way to approach this problem.